# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module - Vue 3 Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, vue-cli, mdxjs

I am currently integrating mdx into my vue 3 typescript project. However, I get the following error when configuring the vue.config.js:

```
yarn run v1.22.11
$ vue-cli-service serve

ERROR  Error loading C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\vue.config.js:
ERROR  Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\vue.config.js from C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\module.js not supported.
Instead change the require of vue.config.js in C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\module.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\vue.config.js from C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\module.js not supported.
Instead change the require of vue.config.js in C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\module.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at exports.loadModule (C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\node_modules\@vue\cli-shared-utils\lib\module.js:79:14)
at Service.loadUserOptions (C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:330:22)
at Service.init (C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:70:30)
at Service.run (C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:215:10)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js:36:9)

error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My vue.config.js:

```
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";

module.exports = {
chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
        .rule('mdx')
        .test(/\.mdx?$/)
        .use('babel-loader')
        .loader('babel-loader')
        .options({plugins: ['@vue/babel-plugin-jsx'], /* Other options… */})
        .end()
        .use('@mdx-js/loader')
        .loader('@mdx-js/loader')
        .options({jsx: true, remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm], /* otherOptions… */})
        .end()
    }
}
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mdx-vue3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdx-js/loader": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@mdx-js/vue": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "remark-gfm": "^3.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
    "@vue/babel-plugin-jsx": "^1.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

The error when im not using `"type": "module"`:

```
C:\Users\Jannik\Desktop\mdx-vue3\vue.config.js:1
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I tried the whole thing with node.js v14 and v16. I also deleted my node_modules each time.

If i rename the file to `vue.config.mjs` the errors disappear, but then the mdx-loader does not work anymore.

Full project: https://github.com/jannikbuscha/mdx-vue3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the devDependencies and renaming `vue.config.js` to `vue.config.mjs` fixed the error:

```
diff --git a/package.json b/package.json
index 884779f..d2f602d 100644
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -9,7 +9,6 @@
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "@mdx-js/loader": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
-    "@mdx-js/mdx": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
     "@mdx-js/vue": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
     "core-js": "^3.6.5",
     "remark-gfm": "^3.0.0",
@@ -17,16 +16,16 @@
     "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
-    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
-    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
+    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.1.0",
+    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.1.0",
 "@vue/babel-plugin-jsx": "^1.1.1",
-    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
-    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
-    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
-    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
+    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "5.0.0-beta.6",
+    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "5.0.0-beta.6",
+    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "5.0.0-beta.6",
+    "@vue/cli-service": "5.0.0-beta.6",
     "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
-    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
-    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
+    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^8.0.0",
+    "eslint": "^8.0.0",
     "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
     "typescript": "~4.1.5"
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is yow module.exports=
`module.exports` is used with `Commonjs` but you have modules in yow package json. You need to change it to `export default`

Comment: Then i get the same error as if i did not use "type": "module" (SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module): https://i.imgur.com/uZeFHvv.png

Comment: if you have TS let it handle them modules, remove `"type":"module"`

Comment: I am currently already doing that. I have linked my github project

Comment: why dont you use vue/cli https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create

Comment: I use @vue/cli 4.5.13 for the project. This is my config: https://i.imgur.com/vZvdLlY.png